# Is there a way to reincarnate Python process from previous execution (stack and code)?

Tags: python

I quick-sort a 1GB file using Python.

The problem is that this sort process is interrupted in predefined intervals of 120 sec (Python terminates).
So every time I'm reaching 120 sec limit I pickle that half-sorted data and let Python exit.

On next invocation I un-pickle previous dump and restart quicksort from the beginning.

**Question:** Is there a way to dump memory and code in such a way that upon next Python invocation that memory/code dump can be loaded and quick-sort just starts where it left off without the need to restart the sort from the beginning of the pickled file?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Pickle is the closest thing you can get to that.

Comment: @Azsgy Thank you. How about Node.js or Java - is it possible there?

Comment: Why is python terminating? Also, if you have a limit on a process lifetime you could fork...

Comment: This feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to me. As a way to solve your *actual* problem: can you pre-sort the file data and then read it into Python knowing that it is sorted? Something like `sort foo.txt -o foo.txt && python my_prog foo.txt` in bash.

Comment: _interrupted in predefined intervals of 120 seconds_ some external something kills it? In linux, you can issue `kill -TSTP <pid>` to background and stop a process. So, its there but not consuming cpu. Then later, `kill -CONT <pid>` and its off and running again.